# How to use Disk Usage Analyzer with encypted home (.Private/ECRYPTFS)

Tags: disk-usage, ecryptfs

When I run Disk Usage Analyzer (Baobab) and click on the first option (`/`), I get this:

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer ecryptfs]

All names are like `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.xyz`.

**QUESTION: How to get the real names?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This inconvenience only happens if you click on the first option (`/`). To avoid this:

1. Run Disk Usage Analyzer
2. Click on the **last option** (`Home folder`)

This will show disk usage for your home folder only, but with the human-readable names.

*[Enhancement request on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-utils/+bug/444282)*